# Css Column Height

Tags: css

I am working on a website at http://173.199.158.106/cspro223/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=87.

I am trying to make the left column the same height as the right column. When this is accomplished the right border of the left column should be the same length as the right column "central" but right now it only extends to the word "advanced search".

anyone can help me with this one?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it a few different ways.

- Give the right column a left border.
- Use a 1px background image repeat-y on the parent container of both columns

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove the border on the left column and apply a border-left to your central div. That way the border will always be the correct height. hope this helps.